# WPF - Windows Forms Interoperation

Tags: wpf, winforms, 3d, windowsformshost

I am abit confused about interoperations between forms. I have an c#.Net application developed using DevExforms. On the other hand I have a XNA application which I want to use it as 3d GUI. But it is diffucult to interact between them. Of course it is not useful, it is ugly too.

So I see a way to develop 3d model viewer app using WPF but WPF controls and windows forms controls needs .Net Framework 4.5 to interact betwwen. But I must use VS2010.

So I am confused. What must I do. How can I easily develop a 3d app with Windows Forms or how can i interact any platform with my app. Actualy if you were me what will you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF controls and WinForms controls don't need .Net framework 4.5 to work together. the interoperability exists before (4.5). take a look in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742474%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes I just see the ElementHost component, my mistake sorry